# Why arguments I pass to the R function doesn`t change value?

Tags: r, pointers, parameter-passing

I'd like to know how to pass argument to function in R the way that this function could edit his value.

E.g., I have function like this:

```
some.function <- function(object){
  object = 3
}

a <- 1
print(a)
[1] 1

some.function(a)
print(a)
[1] 3
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You can use `<<-` or `assign` but don't do that, why not `a <- some.function(a)` ?

Comment: The purpose of a function is not to change global variables but to compute something and return an output value. Using `<<-` or `assign` is rather a bad habit than good practice.

Comment: `<<-` works with objects outside of function, not with passed argument and `assign` doesn`t work at all. Could you explain how to do this?

Comment: Do not create such a function. It is bad practice and not necessary.